# Where reset happens with SR flip-flop

Tags: flipflop, reset

In one of my classes we are learning about circuits. For homework, we have to create a finite state machine for a vending machine using an SR flip-flop. The machine can either take a nickel, dime, or nothing until it gets to at least 15 cents, so it has 4 states (0, 5, 10, and 15 cents). Once the machine receives 15 cents, it dispenses its product. Once in this state, if nothing is deposited it goes to the 0 state; if a nickel is deposited it goes to the 5 cent state; if a dime is deposited, it does to the 10 cent state.

The truth table that I came up with is:

```
Present|Inputs| Next  |        | SR Flip Flop
       |      |       | Output |
Q1  Q0 |D   N |P1   P0|        | S1 R1 S0 R0
_______|______|_______|________|_____________
0   0  | 0  0 | 0   0 |   0    | 0  X 0 X
0   0  | 0  1 | 0   1 |   0    | 0  X 1 0
0   0  | 1  0 | 1   0 |   0    | 1  0 0 X
0   0  | 1  1 | X   X |   X    | X  X X X
_______|______|_______|________|_____________
0   1  | 0  0 | 0   1 |   0    | 0  X X 0
0   1  | 0  1 | 1   0 |   0    | 1  0 0 1
0   1  | 1  0 | 1   1 |   0    | 1  0 X 0
0   1  | 1  1 | X   X |   X    | X  X X X
_______|______|_______|________|_____________
1   0  | 0  0 | 1   0 |   0    | X  0 0 X
1   0  | 0  1 | 1   1 |   0    | X  0 1 0
1   0  | 1  0 | 1   1 |   0    | X  0 1 0
1   0  | 1  1 | X   X |   X    | X  X X X
_______|______|_______|________|_____________
1   1  | 0  0 | 0   0 |   1    | 0  1 0 1
1   1  | 0  1 | 0   1 |   1    | 0  1 X 0
1   1  | 1  0 | 1   0 |   1    | X  0 0 1
1   1  | 1  1 | X   X |   X    | X  X X X
```

Based on this truth table [and the k-maps I made from it], I created the following logic gates:
[image]

My question is, where exactly does the "reset" happen? For example, if I am in the 15 cent state and deposit a nickel, how does it go to the 5 cent stage? Do I have to make the output from "open" loop around? Sorry for such a novice question, I hope that made sense!

Edit: The first two columns are for the present state of the machine, i.e., how much you have deposited so far. So Q0 Q1 = 00 represents the first state (0 cents), Q0 Q1 = 01 represents the second state (5 cents), etc. The next two columns represent adding a nickel or dime. If you are in the state 00 and and 01, you should move to state 01. Since you cannot deposit a nickel and dime simultaneously, we don't care about the the input 11. If you are in state 10 and add 10, you go to state 11 (and don't get any change back!).

Comment: You should explain how the signals are encoded: what are the inputs, what are the states? If you put 10+10, what should happen?

Comment: I added some more information, I hope that helps! If there is anything else I should add, please let me know. Thank you :)

Comment: From a consumer's perspective, the "don't get any change back" system behavior is unfair. Perhaps, you should consider instead the state of the sum of coins collected or handle the situation of having two subsequent nickels collected.

Comment: I agree, but it is part of the homework specification :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reset, given the truth table you provided, happens just because the state **11** of the state machine is mapped in the state **00**; in fact, if you look at the outputs, both states have the same next state, so if the inputs are **00** (buffer), from the state **11** it will go to **00**.

An optimization of the machine would use the Mealy topology, where you map the state **11** in **00** just changing the output if coming from an activating sequence.

### Update

You can udnerstand it better using the diagrams:

#### Moore:

[image]

<sup><sub>Small error: the arrow that goes from (10) to (11) is for both the inputs 01 and 10</sub></sup>

#### Mealy:

[image]

Comment: Those diagrams really helped! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how the coin sensors and output of the machine are implemented, you might need some more states to allow for the fact that a coin might be hitting a switch for an arbitrary length of time; I don't see anything in your machine to handle that.  It's also not clear how long the "dispense product" output is supposed to be active.  A logical possibility would be that "dispense product" should remain active until a signal is returned from the mechanism indicating that the product has been dispensed, whereupon the machine should reset to its start state.

Also, if you are going to use RS latches, you need to design your machine so that if multiple latches switch simultaneously for a state transition, it won't matter whether one switches before the other.  If the machine was sitting in state "01" and a nickel arrived, it would attempt to transition into state "10".  If Q0 and Q1 are RS latches, there is no reason to expect them to switch simultaneously.

If you want to minimize the number of states, the theoretical minimum set, assuming the dispensing mechanism's cycle will last at least as long as a coin input would be:

```
Nothing inserted
Switches active with $0.05
Switches idle with $0.05
Switches active with $0.10
Switches idle with $0.10
Total of $0.15 inserted (switch state irrelevant)
```

Six states, probably allowing a three-bit state machine.  I would conjecture, though, that you might find it easier to use different states for the "switch active with second nickel" and "switch active with first dime" scenarios.  Also, you might be able to reduce circuitry further if you use four latches in two pairs, where the states of the first pair of latches are computed using the outputs of the second, and the second pair of latches copies the state of the first whenever no coins are present.

Comment: I think that this is one of the common exercises on FSM, nothing that involves real implementation

Comment: @clabacchio: If I were interested in a practical implementation, I wouldn't be trying to build a six-state FSM--I'd use a micro.  An exercise in building an FSM using RS latches, however, should expect a solver to ensure that any legitimate input transition which is valid in a particular state will always cause the machine to reach a legitimate, stable state within some bounded number of worst-case propagation delays, without relying upon any particular relationship between delays.  If the exercise were using D latches, I would have no problem if there were an explicit assumption...

Comment: ...that coin inputs would be active for exactly one cycle, but from a teaching standpoint I would think it important that students recognize the issues I mentioned.

Comment: Usually the vending machine is used as example for exercises on FSM...these issue are almost always neglected, it's only to understand what is a state, and how to represent transitions

Comment: @clabacchio: If the circuit were using clocked flip flops, and the duration of the coin inputs was specified as one clock cycle, that would be fine. Learning to build synchronous state machines with clocks is good, as is learning to build asynchronous machines. State machines which look asynchronous but will only work if some undefined clock runs at some magical speed aren't so good, though. I have no problem with exercises that rely upon explicitly-stated unrealistic assumptions, or realistic unstated ones, but I dislike ones that rely upon assumptions that are both unrealistic and unstated.